# SQL Server creation failing on Azure due to policies in place

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-policy, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are in the process of creating SQL Server using ARM Template but since there are policies in place we are unable to get SQL Server created following are the 2 policy exceptions:

##[error]Resource 'xxxxx' was disallowed by policy. Error Type: PolicyViolation, Policy Definition Name : SQL Server should use a virtual network service endpoint (NPD), Policy Assignment Name : NPD1a8a9dc8-aef3-421a-93. Error Type: PolicyViolation, Policy Definition Name : Auditing on SQL server should be enabled (NPD), Policy Assignment Name : NPD7885d0ef-a3de-44a3-9a.

Following is the ARM Template we are using and I am not sure why its failing as now we have VNet rules and auditing also enabled as part of the SQL Server creation:

```
{
  "$schema": http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new database server to create."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The location of the database server."
      }
    },
    "serverVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue" : "12.0"
    },
    "administratorLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The account name to use for the database server administrator."
      }
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The password to use for the database server administrator."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new storage account to create."
      }
    },
    "emailAddresses": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Email address for alerts."
      }
    },
    "privateEndpointName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vnetRg": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
              "description": "Resource Group Name of VNet"
          }
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_GRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ]
    },
    "BUSINESS-OWNER": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "COST-CENTER": {
        "type": "int"
    },
    "LIFECYCLE": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "APPLICATION": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "PROJECT-CODE": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TECHNICAL-OWNER": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "GL-CODE": {
      "type": "string"
    } 
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "[parameters('serverVersion')]",
        "minimalTlsVersion": "1.2",
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
      },
      "tags": {
        "BUSINESS-OWNER": "[parameters('BUSINESS-OWNER')]",
        "COST-CENTER": "[parameters('COST-CENTER')]",
        "LIFECYCLE": "[parameters('LIFECYCLE')]",
        "APPLICATION": "[parameters('APPLICATION')]",
        "PROJECT-CODE": "[parameters('PROJECT-CODE')]",
        "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "[parameters('TECHNICAL-OWNER')]",
        "GL-CODE": "[parameters('GL-CODE')]"
      },
      
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "sergiodb1",
          "type": "databases",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "tags": {
          "BUSINESS-OWNER": "[parameters('BUSINESS-OWNER')]",
          "COST-CENTER": "[parameters('COST-CENTER')]",
          "LIFECYCLE": "[parameters('LIFECYCLE')]",
          "APPLICATION": "[parameters('APPLICATION')]",
          "PROJECT-CODE": "[parameters('PROJECT-CODE')]",
          "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "[parameters('TECHNICAL-OWNER')]",
          "GL-CODE": "[parameters('GL-CODE')]"
        },
          "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('serverName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "edition": "Basic",
            "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
          "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/allow-', parameters('subnet1Name'))]",
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]" ],
          "properties": {
              "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetRg'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]",
              "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Default",
          "type": "auditingSettings",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "State": "Enabled",
            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]",
            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
            "retentionDays": 365,
            "auditActionsAndGroups": null,
            "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
            "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
            "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": false
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "DefaultSAP",
          "type": "securityAlertPolicies",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/auditingSettings/Default')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "state": "Enabled",
            "disabledAlerts": null,
            "emailAddresses": "[array(parameters('emailAddresses'))]",
            "emailAccountAdmins": true,
            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]",
            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
            "retentionDays": 365
          }
        },
        
        {
          "name": "VulnerabilityAssessment",
          "type": "vulnerabilityAssessments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/auditingSettings/Default')]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/securityAlertPolicies/DefaultSAP')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "storageContainerPath": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net','/vulnerability-assessment')]",
            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
            "recurringScans": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "emailSubscriptionAdmins": true,
                "emails": []
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('privateEndpointName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
         "[parameters('serverName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subnet": {
          "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetRg'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
        },
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('privateEndpointName')]",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers',parameters('serverName'))]",
              "groupIds": [
                "sqlServer"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "tags": {
        "BUSINESS-OWNER": "[parameters('BUSINESS-OWNER')]",
        "COST-CENTER": "[parameters('COST-CENTER')]",
        "LIFECYCLE": "[parameters('LIFECYCLE')]",
        "APPLICATION": "[parameters('APPLICATION')]",
        "PROJECT-CODE": "[parameters('PROJECT-CODE')]",
        "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "[parameters('TECHNICAL-OWNER')]",
        "GL-CODE": "[parameters('GL-CODE')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: My ARM Template formatting had issues but most important was the REGION for VNet in which the Pvt endpoint was getting created was set to EASTUS2 while the SQL Server was was getting provisioned in EASTUS. After fixing the regions and the ARM template I was able to successfully deploy it. Following is the corrected ARM Template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters":{

     "serverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new database server to create."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The location of the database server."
      }
    },
    "serverVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue" : "12.0"
    },
    "administratorLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The account name to use for the database server administrator."
      }
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The password to use for the database server administrator."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new storage account to create."
      }
    },
    "emailAddresses": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Email address for alerts."
      }
    },
    "privateEndpointName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vnetRg": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
              "description": "Resource Group Name of VNet"
          }
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_GRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ]
    },
    "BUSINESS-OWNER": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "COST-CENTER": {
        "type": "int"
    },
    "LIFECYCLE": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "APPLICATION": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "PROJECT-CODE": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TECHNICAL-OWNER": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "GL-CODE": {
      "type": "string"
    }   
  },
    "variables": {
        "databaseName": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/sample-db')]"
        
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('serverName')]",
                "BUSINESS-OWNER": "xxx",
                "COST-CENTER": "11",
                "LIFECYCLE": "xx",
                "APPLICATION": "xx",
                "PROJECT-CODE": "xx",
                "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "xxx",
                "GL-CODE": "111"
            },
            "kind": "v12.0",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
                "version": "12.0",
                "minimalTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
            "name": "[variables('databaseName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "[variables('databaseName')]",
                "BUSINESS-OWNER": "xxx",
                "COST-CENTER": "11",
                "LIFECYCLE": "xx",
                "APPLICATION": "xx",
                "PROJECT-CODE": "xx",
                "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "xxx",
                "GL-CODE": "111"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "Basic",
                "tier": "Basic",
                "capacity": 5
            },
            "properties": {
                "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
                "edition": "Basic",
                "maxSizeBytes": 104857600,
                "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "Basic",
                "sampleName": "AdventureWorksLT"
            }
           
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('privateEndpointName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "BUSINESS-OWNER": "xxx",
                "COST-CENTER": "11",
                "LIFECYCLE": "xx",
                "APPLICATION": "xx",
                "PROJECT-CODE": "xx",
                "TECHNICAL-OWNER": "xxx",
                "GL-CODE": "111"
            },
            "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetRg'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnet1Name'))]"
                },
                "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                    {
                        "name": "[parameters('privateEndpointName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers',parameters('serverName'))]",
                            "groupIds": [
                                "sqlServer"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
          "name": "Default",
          "type": "auditingSettings",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"],
          "properties": {
            "State": "Enabled",
            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]",
            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
            "retentionDays": 365,
            "auditActionsAndGroups": null,
            "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
            "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
            "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": false
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "DefaultSAP",
          "type": "securityAlertPolicies",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/auditingSettings/Default')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "state": "Enabled",
            "disabledAlerts": null,
            "emailAddresses": "[array(parameters('emailAddresses'))]",
            "emailAccountAdmins": true,
            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://',parameters('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]",
            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
            "retentionDays": 365
          }
        }

            ]
        }
        
        
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure the subnet you are using on the template has assigned the Microsoft.Sql type name, meaning it is already a Virtual Service endpoint.

The following script can add the type name Microsoft.Sql to your subnet. But the script tries the add only if your subnet lacks the type name.

```
### 1. LOG into to your Azure account, needed only once per PS session.  Assign variables.
$yesno = Read-Host 'Do you need to log into Azure (only one time per powershell.exe session)?  [yes/no]'
if ('yes' -eq $yesno) { Connect-AzAccount }

# Assignments to variables used by the later scripts.
# You can EDIT these values, if necessary.

$SubscriptionName = 'yourSubscriptionName'
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "$SubscriptionName"

$ResourceGroupName = 'yourRGName'
$VNetName = 'yourVNetName'
$SubnetName = 'yourSubnetName'
$SubnetAddressPrefix = 'Obtain this value from the Azure portal.' # Looks roughly like: '10.0.0.0/24'

$ServiceEndpointTypeName_SqlDb = 'Microsoft.Sql'  # Do NOT edit. Is official value.

### 2. Search for your virtual network, and then for your subnet.
# Search for the virtual network.
$vnet = $null
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VNetName

if ($vnet -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Caution: No virtual network found by the name '$VNetName'."
    return
}

$subnet = $null
for ($nn = 0; $nn -lt $vnet.Subnets.Count; $nn++) {
    $subnet = $vnet.Subnets[$nn]
    if ($subnet.Name -eq $SubnetName) { break }
    $subnet = $null
}

if ($null -eq $subnet) {
    Write-Host "Caution: No subnet found by the name '$SubnetName'"
    Return
}

### 3. Is your subnet tagged as 'Microsoft.Sql' endpoint server type?
$endpointMsSql = $null
for ($nn = 0; $nn -lt $subnet.ServiceEndpoints.Count; $nn++) {
    $endpointMsSql = $subnet.ServiceEndpoints[$nn]
    if ($endpointMsSql.Service -eq $ServiceEndpointTypeName_SqlDb) {
        $endpointMsSql
        break
    }
    $endpointMsSql = $null
}

if ($null -eq $endpointMsSql) {
    Write-Host "Good: Subnet found, and is already tagged as an endpoint of type '$ServiceEndpointTypeName_SqlDb'."
    return
} else {
    Write-Host "Caution: Subnet found, but not yet tagged as an endpoint of type '$ServiceEndpointTypeName_SqlDb'."

    # Ask the user for confirmation.
    $yesno = Read-Host 'Do you want the PS script to apply the endpoint type name to your subnet?  [yes/no]'
    if ('no' -eq $yesno) { return }
}

### 4. Add a Virtual Service endpoint of type name 'Microsoft.Sql', on your subnet.
$setParams = @{
    Name            = $SubnetName
    AddressPrefix   = $SubnetAddressPrefix
    VirtualNetwork  = $vnet
    ServiceEndpoint = $ServiceEndpointTypeName_SqlDb
}
$vnet = Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig @setParams

# Persist the subnet update.
$vnet = Set-AzVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet

for ($nn = 0; $nn -lt $vnet.Subnets.Count; $nn++) {
    $vnet.Subnets[0].ServiceEndpoints # Display.
}
```

Comment: Thank you @alberto-morillo the subnet I am using already has Microsoft.Sql added as Service Endpoint.

Comment: Excellent! That is not the issue.